# How to move a PIXI DisplayObject?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I have the following files( using last PIXI.js version):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>pixi.js example 1</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #000000;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
        canvas {
            display:block;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="js/pixi.js"></script>
    <script src="js/XALUI/XALUI.js"></script>
    <script src="js/XALUI/Button.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

    // create an new instance of a pixi stage
    var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0x66FF99);

    // create a renderer instance
    var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    // add the renderer view element to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

    requestAnimFrame( animate );

    // create a texture from an image path
    var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("bunny.png");

    // XALUI
    var button = new XALUI.Button(texture);
    stage.addChild(button);

    function animate() {
        button.position.x = button.position.x + 20;

        // render the stage   
        renderer.render(stage);

        requestAnimFrame( animate );
    }

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

js/XALUI/Button.js

```
XALUI.Button = function(texture) {
    PIXI.DisplayObject.call(this);

    this._button = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
}

XALUI.Button.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.DisplayObject.prototype);
XALUI.Button.prototype.constructor = XALUI.Button;

XALUI.Button.prototype._renderWebGL = function(renderSession) {
    this._button._renderWebGL(renderSession);
}

XALUI.Button.prototype._renderCanvas = function(renderSession) {     
    this._button._renderCanvas(renderSession);
};
```

How can I move my button to another position or to an another initial position? I have tried setting the `position.x`:

```
    var button = new XALUI.Button(texture);
    button.position.x = 100;
```

And also tried to set the position of the sprite:

```
    this._button = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
    this._button.position.x = 100;
```

But it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Does the button display correctly, just in the wrong position?

Comment: It display correctly, but in coords (0,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in that you're attaching and moving `XALUI.Button` instead of the inner `PIXI.Sprite`. Setting the position on the inner sprite (`this._button.position.x`) would only work if you had added that `PIXI.Sprite` to the stage. Since DisplayObjects do not contain multiple DisplayObjects, the stage has no reference to the actual sprite. There are a couple of ways to fix this. First, you could inherit from `PIXI.Sprite`

```
XALUI.Button = function(texture) {
  PIXI.Sprite.call(this, texture);
};
XALUI.Button.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.Sprite.prototype);
XALUI.Button.prototype.constructor = XALUI.Button;
```

Or to have it inherit from `DisplayObjectContainer` in the same manner as above but that implies a button will hold multiple graphical objects so do what works best for you. Here's a working example of the first approach.

```js
var XALUI = {};

// Inherits from PIXI.Sprite
XALUI.Button = function(texture) {
  PIXI.Sprite.call(this, texture);
};
XALUI.Button.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.Sprite.prototype);
XALUI.Button.prototype.constructor = XALUI.Button;

// Prepare the stage
var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0x66FF99);
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/1/bunny.png");
var button = new XALUI.Button(texture);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
stage.addChild(button);

// Animate the button
function animate() {
  button.position.x = button.position.x + 5;
  if (button.position.x > window.innerWidth + button.width) {
    button.position.x = -button.width;
  }
  renderer.render(stage);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/v2.0.0/bin/pixi.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know I can't move when using PIXI.DisplayObject